# Multi-site manager MSM or template group

Tags: multi-site-manager

MSM or not to MSM?

I have a site where a specific member group can only access one area of the website, would I be better to use MSM or just stick with a template group?

www.mysite.com/preciousthings
or
www.preciousthings.com

If the member goes to www.mysite.com they will be redirected to the /preciousthings directory.

So apart from having a neater url is there any reason to use MSM over a template group, for security etc, or is it just a lot of work for not much gain?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one section, I think it's too much work (and money) for really no gain. Just add a global conditional for all pages that will redirect visitors who are logged out or in this specific member group to your /preciousthings directory.

```
{if logged_out OR logged_in_member_group_id == 7}{redirect="preciousthings"}{/if}
```

Comment: I definitely agree. MSM adds a lot of complexity to the setup, so unless you absolutely need it, I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the built-in template access control.

In **Design > Templates > Template Manager**. You can click the **Access** link on any template and define who can view this template, and there they are sent if they can't.

[image: Template access control settings]